# How to Compare related strings?

Tags: php, arrays

so i have a problem with my program where i search a name in an array called ArrName then display handsome or beautiful if he/she exist in the array but if the name is not in the array then the program will display the related strings if the string that i searched does not exist inside the array. i have a hard time solving this please help.Here is a my example.

**SAMPLE OUTPUT #1:**

**Names:** Bob, John, Charlie, Bravo, Alpha, Raymond, Kenneth, Rose, Rosel, James

**Searching for:** bob.

**Result:** Bob exist, Bob is handsome

**SAMPLE OUTPUT#2:**

**Names:** Bob, John, Charlie, Bravo, Alpha, Raymond, Kenneth, Rose, Rosel, James

**Searching for:** roger.

**Result:** Roger not found. did you mean:

Rose?

Rosel?

here is my code so far:

```
    <html>
<body>
    <?php
        $arrNumbers = array('jonel','jon','john','rosel','rosil','rose','ramon','ramin','ramoon','kenneth','keneth','kennet','joy','juy');
        $arrboys = array('jonel','jon','john','ramon','ramin','ramoon','kenneth','keneth','kennet');
        $arrgirls = array('rosel','rosil','rose','joy','juy');
        $strsearch = 'rosel';
        $count = 0;
        $badd = 0;
        $gadd = 0;

        foreach($arrNumbers as $value)// checks if name exists
        {
            if($value == $strsearch)
            {
                $count = $count + 1;

            }
            else
            {
                $count = $count + 0;

            }
        }

        if($count > 0)// if name exists, checks if the name is from a boy or a girl
        {
            //boys
            foreach($arrboys as $value)// checks if the name is from the boys
            {
                if($value == $strsearch)
                {
                    $badd = $badd + 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    $badd = $badd + 0;
                }
            }
            if($badd > 0)
            {
                echo $strsearch.' is handsome';
            }

            // girls
            foreach($arrgirls as $value)// checks if the name is from the girls
            {
                if($value == $strsearch)
                {
                    $gadd = $gadd + 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    $gadd = $gadd + 0;
                }
            }
            if($gadd > 0)
            {
                echo $strsearch.' is beautiful';
            }
        }
        else// if the name does not exists
        {
          // this is the part where i dont know what to do.
          // this part suppose to display all the names related to the name that is 
          // being searched.
            echo 'did you mean';
        }
    ?>
</body>
```

Comment: Look at in_array() and similar_text()

Comment: Or if you want to get your hands dirty, check out the [Damerau-Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance) or [simlar algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching)...

Answer (score 0):

Why are you checking occurrence in $arrNumbers array as $arrboys and $arrgirls are substring of $arrNumbers.

Use below code

```
<?php
        $arrNumbers = array('jonel','jon','john','rosel','rosil','rose','ramon','ramin','ramoon','kenneth','keneth','kennet','joy','juy');
        $arrboys = array('jonel','jon','john','ramon','ramin','ramoon','kenneth','keneth','kennet');
        $arrgirls = array('rosel','rosil','rose','joy','juy');
        $strsearch = 'rosel';
        $flag = '';
        for($i=0;$i<sizeof($arrboys);$i++)
        {
            //echo $arrboys[$i].' ';
            if($strsearch == $arrboys[$i]);
            $flag = 'boy';
        }

        for($i=0;$i<sizeof($arrgirls);$i++)
        {
            //echo $arrboys[$i].' ';
            if($strsearch == $arrgirls[$i]);
            $flag = 'girl';
        }
        if($flag == 'boy')
        {
            echo $strsearch.' exist, '. $strsearch.' is handsome';
        }
        if($flag == 'girl')
        {
            echo $strsearch.' exist, '. $strsearch.' is beautiful';
        }
        else
        {
            echo  $strsearch.' not found. did you mean:';
        }
        ?>
```